# "Война войной, а обед по расписанию"

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошло выражение (поговорка)?

> Война войной, а обед по расписанию

Comment: These words are claimed to be said by, Frederick William I, King of Prussia.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the origin of the phrase? If yes, then where?

Comment: The phrase is attributed to Frederick William I of Prussia and, allegedly, refers to the fact that soldiers need to be fed, as otherwise they will be thinking about food, not war.

Comment: @Olga I've tried to google it - the google returns not relevant results, and I'm not familiar with any etymology dictionary.

Comment: Half of the sources say that author is Suvorov, and other that Frederick William. Who is right? Any proofs?

Comment: Also I would like to know are any dashes required in the phrase?

Comment: @hazzik: the word *расписание* has acquired the modern meaning ("schedule") no earlier than mid-XIX, so it definitely cannot be Suvorov and hardly Frederick William I. Most probably, it's a latest invention back attributed to them. No dashes are required, your punctuation is right.

Comment: @Quassnoi If it really was Frederick William I, he definitely did not say in in Russian (but probably in German).  The phrase we're discussing is the translation.  I don't know German, so can't really search for the original phrase, but it's quite likely that the original German word was in use during Frederick William I.

Comment: @AleksG: such an aphorism can hardly become notable out of blue. It could evoke from a contemporary translation of a primary source (impossible per above), a more recent translation of a primary source (very unlike to exist), or an anecdote from a more recent secondary source (would be easily searchable).

Comment: I'll slightly correct the sentence. Not exactly "по расписанию" but "по распорядку". Because of special term "распорядок" that means almost the same as "расписание" but mostly used in military language (not even military but we speak about this exact case).

Comment: First time I heard this proverb was while I was watching a film about World War II "В бой идут одни старики" about group of young soviet pilots. I beleive for many people this is the "origin" of the proverb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эту фразу произнес великий русский актер Леонид Броневой в фильме "Тот самый Мюнхгаузен".
Броневой играл в этом прекрасном фильме роль герцога — курфюрста Ганновера.

Comment: This may be true, however this doesn't seem to correlate to any historical records.

Comment: @AleksG, I agree, but still this answer is valuable, since actually many of native speakers are aware of this quote mainly because of this movie.

Answer (score -1):

Фридрих Вильгельм I
(Source: http://www.aforizm.info/author/fridrikh-vilgelm-I/)

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Please provide an authoritative source for your claim. The site you are linking to is just a collection of unsourced quotes.